# Deleting an object in a vector

Tags: c++

I am trying to delete an element in a vector of Objects. The vector is filled with instances of `Object` and at some point, I want to remove a certain element in a vector not by index, but by the element itself.

A simple example would be:

```
std::vector< string > strVector;
strVector.push_back( "abc" );
strVector.push_back( "def" );
strVector.push_back( "ghi" ); // So strVector should contain "abc", "def", and "ghi"
```

How do I remove "ghi" from that vector? Note that I don't know where "ghi" is in that vector.

```
// Something like this. Assume strVector = [ "abc", "cba", "ccb", "bac", "aaa" ]
strVector.removeElement( "ccb" );
```

A more relevant example to what I a working on:

```
class MyClass {
   std::vector< Object > myObjVector;
   void main( ARGS ) {
      for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
         Object myObject = Object( );
         myObjVector.push_back( myObject );
      }

      int j = getANumber( ); // j could be any number within the size of the vector
      Object myOtherObject = myObjectVector.at( j );

      // How do I erase myOtherObject (which is an object inside the vector) ?
      removeFromVector( myOtherObject );
   }
}
```

I hope the question's clear. Thanks in advance.

*EDIT*: I figured it out, thanks to all those who answered. The trick was to give the class something unique that identifies it (like a name or a tag, as long as they are guaranteed to be unique) then use the [erase-remove idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom) to remove the object from the array.

Comment: do you have duplicates inside vector?

Comment: No, I don't. After I create an instance of `Object` I immediately push it into the vector, meaning, all the elements of the vector are just newly created ones.

Comment: Check some [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), it should help find e.g. the [`erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) function.

Comment: @Joachim: I've tried `erase()` but it doesn't accept `Object` type as argument.

Comment: Except for needless inefficiency (which however the compiler is likely to optimize away), ` Object myObject = Object();` is equivalent to `Object myObject;`, and even this variable is redundant. This and some other things indicate that you're coming from a Java background. So it is *likely* that you think that the static type `Object`s in the vector can have dynamic types that are derived classes. That's not so in C++. Indeed, the whole idea of a Java-like common `Object` class is foreign to C++, and is in general counter-productive in C++. Simply don't.

Comment: Also see [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find).

Comment: @Cheers: Yeah, I came from Java and I find this very very weird and is giving me a very hard time. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your use-case has no duplicates, then you are better off using an `std::set` and using the [std::set::erase](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/erase) which takes a value.

```
std::set< string > strSet;
strSet.insert( "abc" );
strSet.insert( "def" );
strSet.insert( "ghi" );
strSet.insert( "ccb" );

strSet.erase("ccb");
```

If you need to cope with duplicates, then you have to specify the desired behaviour of the removal. Should it remove one or all of the elements matching a value? Do you care about preserving the order of the remaining elements? If you require using a vector, then lokk at the [erase-remove idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom). But note that `std::vector::erase` has linear time complexity, whereas the relevant variant of `std::set::erase` has logarithmic time complexity. And erase-remove would remove *all* elements equal to the given value.

**Note**: if you want to use an `std::set` for a user defined type, you must provide either a less-than `bool operator<(const UserType&) const` or a comparison function or functor, implementing [strict weak ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_weak_ordering).

Comment: No, there should be no duplicates, theoretically, since I'm pushing things right after they are instantiated. There's no need for the order to be preserved, just remove the `Object` instance in a/an vector/array/set of `Object`s

Comment: @LanceGray: You say that there should be no duplicates, but in your example, you insert 10 identical objects in the vector (well, we don't have the definition of `Object`, so this is a guess). Do you know the distinction between reference semantics and value semantics? For instance, do you realize that `std::string s1("s")` and `std::string s2("s")`, even though they are two different objects, are equal? `s1 == s2`.

Comment: @LucTouraille So they are equal because of the value? So in the loop, I'm pushing the same object (`myObject`) into the vector and C++ treats it as ten copies of the same `myObject`? I'm sorry I'm totally confused by how arrays/vectors work in C++.

Comment: @LanceGray Yes, but the caveat is that in C++ you can define equality between objects of a given type. In fact, you have to define it if you want to find `Objects` using some algorithms (others require less-than comparison). So if you want two similar objects to be different, you have to provide a means to distinguish them (for example, some kind of unique identifier that you can use in the equality comparison).

Comment: @juanchopanza So if I make some kind of "tag" property and added a `operator==` on the class to check that "tag", I will be able to successfully get a specific object and an vector of objects?

Comment: @LanceGray yes, as long as you can guarantee that the tags are unique. This isn't as trivial as it may seem.

Comment: @juanchopanza I tried it and it worked fine. I added an `m_objectName` member variable and an `operator==`. Really solved my problem. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

If you must use a `vector`, then use [`erase(remove())`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

strVector.erase(std::remove(strVector.begin(), strVector.end(), "ghi"),
                strVector.end());
```

this will remove all instances of `"ghi"` from `strVector`.

Comment: No, I am not limited to a vector. I also tried using `erase( remove( ) )` but it still doesn't work. (I am coding in Xcode and cocos2d-x by the way)

Comment: It gives an error saying "Invalid operands to binary expression ('Object' and 'const Object')" (where 'Object' is the name of the class I wrote). It also points to a lot of `if` lines on the `stl_algo.h` header.

Comment: @LanceGray, you would need to specify an `operator==()` for your `Object` or use `std::remove_if()` and specify a predicate. See demo http://ideone.com/iVYT1 .

Comment: I added an `operator==()` in the Object but now I get a linker error saying I made a duplicate `operator==()` (which is probably caused by the Xcode compiler)

Comment: @LanceGray, put declaration in `.h` and the definition in `.cpp`.

Answer (score 1):

If the objects in the vector support equality, and that's the condition
for removal, then you can use:

```
v.erase( std::remove( v.begin(), v.end(), "ghi" ), v.end() );
```

Otherwise, you'll need `remove_if`, with a functional object (or lambda,
if you have C++11) which returns true if the element is to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Object
{
public:
    Object(int n){secret_num = n;}
    virtual ~Object(){}
    int getSecretNum(){return secret_num;}

private:
    int secret_num;
};

int main()
{

    int index= -1;
    Object *urobj = new Object(104);
    std::vector<Object*> urvector;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
       Object *obj = new Object(i+1);
       urvector.push_back(obj);

    }

    urvector.push_back(urobj);

    for(int j = 0; j < urvector.size(); ++j)
    {
        Object *tmp = urvector.at(j);
        std::cout << tmp->getSecretNum() << std::endl;
        if(urobj == tmp)
            index = j; 
    }

    if(index == -1)
       std::cout << " not match " << std::endl;
    else 
       std::cout << " match " << index << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```